Angular 16 - global import in all tests
I'm using Angular 16 with Karma/Jasmine. I want to have a module be imported by default in all my tests but am unable to find where this can be configured. I saw this post which makes use of a test.ts file, but my project does not include this.
How can I include this test.ts file in order to globally import a module in all my tests?

Well, I managed to answer my own question before posting but I'm putting it here anyway.
From Angular 15 onward, the test.ts file is no longer automatically generated. However, you can still manually create this:
src/test.ts:
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyModuleToImport} from 'somewhere...';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import 'zone.js/testing';

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  [BrowserDynamicTestingModule, MyModuleToImport],
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

angular.json: (add "main": "src/test.ts")

...

        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

tsconfig.spec.json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine"]
  },
  "files": ["src/test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}


